# Android pom.xml error

Tags: android, maven

I have never used `POM` nor `MAVEN`, could anyone please explain this issue?

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find 
com.mastercard.mobile:MMPPUI-SDK:pom:1.2.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached 
in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of 
central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the dependency/parent `com.mastercard.mobile:MMPPUI-SDK:pom:1.2.1` from maven central where it does not exist. This means either you haven't configured your settings.xml file correctly to use your companies repository manager or you forget to install the appropriate parent in your local repository.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I don't know anything about this though, it's an android project, where can I find my local repository

Comment: I didn't have my folders com.mastercard.mobile in my local repository, thank you

Comment: IN the contrary the message `was cached in the local repository` exactly stated that.

Comment: you are right actually and I had to do an `update project configuration` for that to take effect